# MongoDB - Update entire object of entry if subset/field is max

Tags: mongodb

I have an entry that looks something like:

```json
{
  rank: {
    score: 5,
    date: '2020-01-01'
  }
}
```

Let's say I wanted to update the `rank` object only if the new rank's score is higher than the existing one.  For example, I have a new rank that looks like:

```json
{
  score: 10,
  date: '2022-12-12'
}
```

I know that the `$max` operator exists, but I'm not sure how to use it so that if the new score is higher, also update the date field - otherwise, do not update date.  In other words, `date` should only be updated if `score` is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add that to the query condition of your update, that way if it doesn't matter, no document will match the update.

```
const newRank = { score: 10, date: '2022-12-12' }
db.collection.updateOne(
{ 
  'rank.score': {$lt: newRank.score},
   // whatever else needs to be here
},
{
  $set: {
    rank: newRank
  }
})
```